OpenXPKI import existing certificates
We have installed OpenXPKI-3.24 on FreeBSD-13.2p9 (running in a jail).  We have completed the setup and installed the issuing CA key and certificate.  User access is configured using the suggested yaml datastore.  The webui is working.
The issuing CA that we have imported into OpenXPKI is the one for our existing PKI.  This has existed since 2016 and there are about 110 certificates issued, most expired but many still active. These need to be imported into OpenXPKI in such a fashion as to have them recognized as belonging to the issuing CA.  I cannot find a way to do this from reading the documentation.
A prior attempt at solving this resulted in all these certificates being imported.  Examination of the imported certificates shows that the assigned realm is the correct one.  Examination of the certificate chains show that these are also correct. However, none of them show up in the certificate list for that realm.
What additional steps are required for these certificate to appear in the webui certificate list and search?
